# How can i pass the parameter “username” to "/" router with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a db operation in login post router, when db operation callback success, I got a username value, and how I can pass this username to the "/" router?

```
router.post('/login', (req, res)=> {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = common.md5(req.body.password + common.MD5_SUFFIX);
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM admin_table WHERE username='${username}'`, (err, data)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('database error').end();
        } else {
            if (data.length == 0) {
                res.status(404).send('no this admin').end();
            } else {
                if (data[0].password == password) {
                    req.session['admin_id']=data[0].ID;
                    res.redirect('/');

                } else {
                    res.status(404).send('This password is not incorrect!').end();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
router.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('admin/login.ejs',{layout:'/admin/layout.ejs',title:'Login'});
});
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('admin/index.ejs',{layout:'/admin/layout.ejs',title:'Index',username:username});
});
```

Such as in post login router, I got a username is "ollie", when db operation is ending, the router redirect "/", I can got the username "ollie" in the "/" router .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a session. E.g. where you configure the express app, use this:

```
if (data[0].password == password) {
    req.session['admin_id']=data[0].ID;
    req.session.username = data.username;
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Then later you can access that, e.g.

```
router.get('/route', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session && req.session.username);
    res.end(`Hi ${req.session && req.session.username}`)
});
```

And please, please, please do not use md5 in any authentication schemes, even example code.